# Unity C#: How to rebind buttons via script while game is running?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Title says it all, I'd like to implement a controls menu so the player can rebind controls, which changes the positive input key of a button in the Input Manager. But I can't find anything about it online.

How would I go about changing the positive key for a button while ingame?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I believe you can't set Input Manager values via code at all. That's probably why you didn't find anything about it.

---

You've got two alternatives:

1. Use the "Input System" aka. the new input system that is available as a package. It is not as easy to use as the legacy input system, but you should [check it out](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/index.html). It's also [open source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/).
2. Use an asset store package. I've tested [Rewired](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676) in the past and found it extremely powerful, especially compared to the legacy input system.

---

Personally, I'd first go with option 1 and see if you are happy with it. It's an official package and not 3rd party. Option 2 is still there, if you have issues with option 1, but it'll probably cost you money.